# How to break each rows into multiple rows in Spark DataFrame using scala

Tags: scala, dataframe

I have a dataframe having data as below

```
Key  Today  MTD  QTD  HTD  YTD 
K1   10     20   10   20   50
K2   20     30   20   10   60
```

I am looking output like

```
Key  PRD     Amt
K1   Today   10
K1   MTD     20
K1   QTD     10
K1   HTD     20
K1   YTD     50
```

I tried working with Pivot but it gives other way. I am not sure if I can use flat map or map? Please advise.

Comment: converting a coulmn to row does not make sense. In general for any table like strucutre we call a vertical sequence as column and a horizontal sequence as row. But if we look at a column or row without the context of a table then both are just sequences.

Comment: Also I don't think anyone can understand your question by looking at its current state. I will try to reformat it from my understanding of your question.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I beg to differ. There is a reason why the "melt.data.frame" function exists in R -- I use it all the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import spark.implicits._

val list = List(("K1", 10, 20, 10, 20,50), ("K2", 20, 30, 20, 10, 60))
val yourDF = sc.parallelize(list).toDF("Key", "Today", "MTD", "QTD", "HTD", "YTD")

// yourDF.show()
// +---+-----+---+---+---+---+
// |Key|Today|MTD|QTD|HTD|YTD|
// +---+-----+---+---+---+---+
// | K1|   10| 20| 10| 20| 50|
// | K2|   20| 30| 20| 10| 60|
// +---+-----+---+---+---+---+

val newDataFrame = yourDF
  .rdd
  .flatMap(row => {
    val key = row.getString(0)
    val todayAmt = row.getInt(1)
    val mtdAmt = row.getInt(2)
    val qtdAmt = row.getInt(3)
    val htdAmt = row.getInt(4)
    val ytdAmt = row.getInt(5)

    List(
      (key, "today", todayAmt),
      (key, "MTD", mtdAmt),
      (key, "QTD", qtdAmt),
      (key, "HTD", htdAmt),
      (key, "YTD", ytdAmt)
    )
  })
  .toDF("Key", "PRD", "Amt" )

// newDataFrame.show()
// +---+-----+---+
// |Key|  PRD|Amt|
// +---+-----+---+
// | K1|today| 10|
// | K1|  MTD| 20|
// | K1|  QTD| 10|
// | K1|  HTD| 20|
// | K1|  YTD| 50|
// | K2|today| 20|
// | K2|  MTD| 30|
// | K2|  QTD| 20|
// | K2|  HTD| 10|
// | K2|  YTD| 60|
// +---+-----+---+
```

Comment: Thanks this helps :)

Comment: when I run this code on my streaming dataframe, I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any`. Any idea why?